# RestKit 2 PUT request for some Object

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

Server team wants to separate out 2 PUT requests for one Item class like this -

```
PUT '<server>/item/:itemId'
```

and

```
PUT '<server>/item/:itemId/like'
```

I am using the following code in the initializer:

```
RKObjectManager *sharedRKObjectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [sharedRKObjectManager managedObjectStore];
// Create the mapping for the News entity.
RKEntityMapping *responseMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:ENTITY_ITEM inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"id":    @"itemId",
                                                      }];
// Create a response descriptor and add it to the RKObjectManager object.
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                   pathPattern:UPDATE_ITEM_URL
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[sharedRKObjectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Item class] pathPattern:UPDATE_ITEM_URL method:RKRequestMethodAny]];
[sharedRKObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

And then the following is the call:

```
+(void)updateItem:(Item*)item
      withParams:(NSDictionary*)params
         success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
         failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    [CMLRKSharedManager setUpHeaders];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] putObject:item path:nil parameters:params success:success failure:failure];
}
```

My ques is - can i use the same functions for these 2 requests? Can i append the url any other way?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use the `RKRoute` in this case. Explicitly supply the appropriate path when you call `put...`.

Note that you should also have 2 response descriptors because the path patterns are different.

Comment: How will the appropriate mapping be detected without a RKRoute? Can you pls point me to an example? Thanks!

Comment: The router is used to determine the path based on a class type, not a mapping. The mapping is determined from the request descriptor. If you specify the path then you don't need a route.

Answer (score 0):

in case it helps anyone.. here is the code to do this

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"item/%@/like", itemId];
[CMLRKSharedManager updateItem:item params:nil path:path success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Displaying user info %@", [mappingResult firstObject]);
} failure:nil];
```